# No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -102

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

i have a problem. Some sql in my program could be written by the user. So I don't know which table or which columns are in this sql. Therefore i want to detect which column names are in the sql. But if a date is in the sql i get the No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -102 error.
How could i handle that? I am using hibernate 3.6 or 4.1.3 with java. My database is an oracle database. The dialect is org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect.

I really don't know what is in the sql.

Here is my code:

```
SQLQuery q=session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id = 2"); 
q.setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE); 
List<Map<String,Object>> aliasToValueMapList=q.list();
for(Map<String,Object> map : aliasToValueMapList){
    System.out.println(map.keySet());
    break;
}
```

I hope anyone knows a solution for this problem.

Greetz

Comment: is it hibernate 3.6 or 4.1.3? What version of java are you using? Is it Oracle 10g database?

Comment: i am using both. i want to use 4.1.3 after next week so i test it. at the moment i am using 3.6. my database is an oracle 11g instance but there is no dialect for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is attempt to return a column that the JDBC ResultSetMetaData is reporting a type (-102) which Hibernate does not know how to read.  You need to register the type  for that column with the query using org.hibernate.SQLQuery#addScalar or you may not be able to use that transformer and actually define the entire result set mapping to your entity org.hibernate.SQLQuery#addRoot/org.hibernate.SQLQuery#addEntity.  See the docs for usage

Comment: yes i now that but i don't know that there is date in the sql and i don't know the table so i can't map that to an specific class.

Comment: "there is date in the sql"? not sure what that means. well find out what type your driver is reporting as -102 and map that in your dialect.  that is another solution.  -102 is not a standard JDBC type.

Comment: ok...the -102 means timestamp / date type. how can i map that in my dialect. the error comes only if there is a timestamp / date in my query.

Comment: That is not the JDBC standard type mapping for timestamp or date types : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.sql.Types.ARRAY.  I'd first be curious why your databases is mapping them to non-standard JDBC codes.  Beyond that, actually getting Hibernate to understand this as a JDBC type code would mean writing a Dialect (extending the appropriate supplied Dialect) and calling Dialect#registerHibernateType for this -102 type.

Comment: how could i do that? have you an example?

Comment: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/d51a0d0c7830818d58fc6e023b4b74f911167eff/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/Dialect.java#L181  I suppose you would want something like `registerHibernateType( -102, StandardBasicTypes.TIMESTAMP.getName() );`

Comment: great! this works. thank you now i am dynamic with the content of my sql and i get no -102!!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you use session.createQuery() this will use your dialect to talk to the database using Hibernate Query Language. but if you use createSQLQuery() you have to use PL/SQL to talk to the oracle.

Comment: I guess this has to be the answer to the question. Generally it's not advisable to use session.createSQLQuery

Comment: if i do that then i have to change my code like that: Query lu=session.createQuery("FROM tbl WHERE id = 2"); but then the error: is not mapped [FROM tbl WHERE id = 2] come up. but i can't map because i don't know the tablename